# I've been downvoted, can I find out which question or answer was downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes

I'm not interested in finding out who did the voting, but on SF I've dropped from 1211 to 1209 but it doesn't appear in the recent rep list.

Comment: Downvoted here too! Oh, the irony!

Answer (score 5):

You will not see downvotes on your Recent Activity page if you have more than 5 posts that have received upvotes or were accepted.  That page, by default, will show your 'Top 5 Posts' (as stated on the page), so if you have 5 posts with positive points, the ones with negative points will have been sorted off the list.

You *can* see the whole list.  The number in the summary box indicating 'reputation earned' is a hyperlink.  If you want to see the entire list that is used to calculate the 'total reputation earned' for this reputation day, click on the number.

Comment: +1, Annoying user profile page organization.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the recent activity page (the envelope next to your username). Also you can zoom into the graph showing the growth (or not) and this summarises the activity, too.

Answer (score 3):

As Unsliced says, there's the recent activity graph. You can also use my [Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?sf=2277). It looks like it was the ["Who uses Mac OS X Server and Why"](https://serverfault.com/questions/49639/49671#49671) answer in this case.

Comment: Not a bad tracker ;)

Comment: Reptutation? :-) Sorry, can't edit your answer so this will do. ;-)

Comment: I really like the minimalist GUI (this is not sarcasm)

Answer (score 1):

If you use your recent activity page, you can go to the reputation tab, which will show all reputation activity for the selected period. For the OP and today (8/22), this would be the page, for other's sub your userid where the OP's is.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/132167?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2009-08-22&EndDate=2009-08-22

Answer (score -1):

The recent activity page doesn't show negative rep (that I've ever seen).

Go to the reputation tab to show a complete list of everything. You may need to click "today" too to get a list of today's activity. For reasons I forget it doesn't default to showing the complete info for today. It might be some of today or some of today and some of yesterday. I think it's performance related.

If you don't see it there try yesterday and so forth until you find it.

You can also go to the reputation graph on your profile page and click a small window to see what downvotes questions have received (adjusting the window as necessary).

Comment: Recent Activity shows negative rep. It shows the total of each question which was voted on. It is red, when it is negative. You don't get any downvotes, I assume ;)

Comment: Ive seen the occasional - rep in my profile