# How to find out which question or answer was downvoted?

Tags: support, down-votes

I would like to know which post earned me a downvote.  I don't see it showing up in the reputation tracker.

**This is a possible duplicate of:**  [I've been downvoted, can I find out which question or answer was downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12576/ive-been-downvoted-can-i-find-out-which-question-or-answer-was-downvoted)

**Except that the answers there don't help me** -- I tried them all and they don't work (or I don't understand the instructions enough to follow them).

That question was two years old -- has the system changed?

Update:  **This was on SO**

Comment: Don't forget, loss of rep also could be due to a flagged question or answer being deleted.

Comment: You're right, your [reputation tracker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/894284/matt-fenwick?tab=reputation) doesn't show anything.  What makes you think you were downvoted?

Comment: @Kev -- I thought down-votes were the only way to get -2.

Comment: Try going to `/reputation` and doing a recalculation; maybe the downvote was undone and the system hasn't realized it yet?

Comment: Hm.  This is an interesting case of comment reply difficulties.  *I* got a notification for that comment, but I think it was intended for Kev♦.  (This should work, I don't get notified by my own comments->) @Kev - Did you get a notification from Matt's comment?

Comment: @KevinVermeer - funnily enough I didn't, just your 2*Hm. This is an interesting case of comment reply*" comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean your SO profile. If you go to the [`reputation` tab on your profile and sort it by time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894284/matt-fenwick?tab=reputation#page_1-view_time), you'll see that the last time you were downvoted was on Nov 8th for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053867/analyzing-a-programming-language?noredirect=1). It has since been moved to Programmers.SE

Looking at the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8053867/revisions), I see that the question was closed at one point. So the downvote you received was most likely a system generated automatic downvote for off-topic questions when they're closed.

[image]

Comment: No, that's not it.  It was today.

Comment: On which profile?

Comment: SO -- I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: There's nothing on your profile.. Are you sure you didn't give out two downvotes?

Comment: No, I didn't -- but wouldn't that be reflected in my rep tracker, too?  It says that I gave one downvote yesterday, which is true.

Comment: Yes, but we won't be able to see it in your rep page. It's visible only to you. Also, it could've been a revoked downvote or downvotes on a deleted question. So try going to `/reputation` and auditing it.

Comment: I don't see anything about that -- when I hover over my name, it says 38 rep for the day, but when I click on the reputation tab it only says that I've gotten 4 up-votes today.  I'll try the audit thing, thanks!

Comment: I just realized I don't know how to do the /reputation audit.  Where do I start?

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and click the button at the bottom.

Comment: @MattFenwick Go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and scroll to the very bottom and click "Trigger Reputation Recalc".

Comment: That did it, thanks!  That was a very confusing problem for me.